# Connect a third party VPC with existing VPC Network Peering setup - GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, vpc

I've two VPCs network connected via VPC Network Peering. How can I connect another VPC which is not within GCP? I reckon I have to use Cloud VPN to connect the three?

Do I have to disable the existing VPC Network Peering before I can set up Cloud VPN? Is there a better way to connect the three?

Comment: Are you looking for this https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/networking/google-cloud-networking-in-depth-simplify-routing-between-your-vpcs-with-vpc-peering

Answer (score 0):

To connect to an on-premise network, you have to use [Interconnect](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/interconnect) or [Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn).

These services are totally compatible with the VPC Peering that you've already created, and if you define the routing correctly, you'll be able to reach from the on-premise the two VPCs and vice-versa.